# Transfer Learning with Tensorflow (MobileNet)

Tags: tensorflow, transfer-learning, mobilenet

In Transfer learning, I think my model.fit_generator goes in an infinite loop. I don't know-how. Here is my Colab notebook link https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1o9GNCQdMeh4HZdiZ5QAjiDDkixn-OsXx

[Here is the image of model.fit_generator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9cTqk.jpg)

Comment: did you check my answer below? Let me know whether it was helpful or not. Thanks

Comment: Please check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) on what you need to do after getting an answer. Basically selecting an answer as "Answer to your question", then it will help others to follow your post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you update the last line as follows then it takes around 40 seconds for 5 epochs.

from

```
model.fit_generator(train_generator, epochs=5, validation_data=valid_generator)
```

to

```
model.fit_generator(train_generator, epochs=5, steps_per_epoch=len(train_generator), validation_data=valid_generator, validation_steps=len(valid_generator))
```

Please check the description of what is expected when the input to model.fit is a generator. So when 'steps_per_epoch' is None, the epoch will run until the input dataset is exhausted. So the generator running infinitely if your dataset is infinitely repeating dataset.

> steps_per_epoch: Integer or None. Total number of steps (batches of
>   samples) before declaring one epoch finished and starting the next
>   epoch. When training with input tensors such as TensorFlow data
>   tensors, the default None is equal to the number of samples in your
>   dataset divided by the batch size, or 1 if that cannot be determined.
>   If x is a tf.data dataset, and 'steps_per_epoch' is None, the epoch
>   will run until the input dataset is exhausted. When passing an
>   infinitely repeating dataset, you must specify the steps_per_epoch
>   argument. This argument is not supported with array inputs.